# How to trigger multiple message in one function in Elm 0.18?

Tags: elm

I want to trigger multiple messages when window resize in subscription.

Something like:

```
subscription : Model -> Sub Msg
subscription model =
  Window.resizes (\{width, height} ->
    Sidebar "hide"
    Layout "card"
    Search <| Name ""
    Screen width height
  )
```

How do I active them at once?

Comment: Maybe not the point but in this particular example I would suggest having only one message e.g `OnWindowResize` and then in update changing all the model attributes you need.

Comment: @Sebastian's comment should be elevated to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I don't say it is a good thing to do in the case at hand (the logic should reside in the `update` function), you can do this by batching a list of signals like this:

```
subscription : Model -> Sub Msg
subscription model =
    Sub.batch 
        [ Window.resizes (\_ -> Sidebar "hide")
        , Window.resizes (\_ -> Layout "card")
        , Window.resizes (\_ -> Search <| Name "")
        , Window.resizes (\{width, height} -> Screen width height)
        ]
```

See [this](https://runelm.io/c/f84)!

Answer (score 6):

I'm also interested in seeing what other would answer.
But here is what I would do.

In short, you can make a single parent message which calls other child messages.
`andThen` function just helps to concatenate the update calls.

```
andThen : Msg -> ( Model, Cmd msg ) -> ( Model, Cmd msg )
andThen msg ( model, cmd ) =
    let
        ( newmodel, newcmd ) =
            update msg model
    in
        newmodel ! [ cmd, newcmd ]


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd msg )
update msg model =
    case Debug.log "message" msg of
        DoABC ->
            update DoA model
                |> andThen DoB
                |> andThen DoC
```

Comment: This `andThen` function is BTW almost the same as what can be found in the [elm-return package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Fresheyeball/elm-return/6.0.3/Return#andThen).

Comment: As a sidenote for future readers, the `newmodel ! [ cmd, newcmd ]` line is a shorthand for `(newmodel, Cmd.batch[cmd,newcmd])`